# Understanding python code

Tags: python

ab.py

```
from ddr import Options
debugElmo     = int(Options.env['GG_DEBUG_ELMO'])
postdevElmo   = int(Options.env['GG_POST_DEV_ELMO'])
```

Options.py

```
vars_of_interest = (
    'AA_PYTHON',
    'GG_POST_DEV_ELMO',
    'GG_DEBUG_ELMO',
    )
env = dict((var, os.getenv(var, 0)) for var in vars_of_interest)
```

I am not sure what is going on for `env = dict((var, os.getenv(var, 0)) for var in vars_of_interest)` as I am fairly new to python

is env a function in python in Options.py?
what is dict()?
Is var the variable from `int(Options.env['GG_DEBUG_ELMO'])`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can often learn what Python code is doing by looking at its pieces in the Python interpreter:

```
>>> vars_of_interest
('AA_PYTHON', 'GG_POST_DEV_ELMO', 'GG_DEBUG_ELMO')

>>> import os

>>> [(var, os.getenv(var, 0)) for var in vars_of_interest]
[('AA_PYTHON', 0), ('GG_POST_DEV_ELMO', 0), ('GG_DEBUG_ELMO', 0)]

>>> env = dict((var, os.getenv(var, 0)) for var in vars_of_interest)
>>> env
{'AA_PYTHON': 0, 'GG_DEBUG_ELMO': 0, 'GG_POST_DEV_ELMO': 0}
```

`env = dict(...)` makes `env` a `dict`. If you are ever unsure what an object is, you can always ask it what its type is:

```
>>> type(env)
dict
```

A `dict` is a mapping between keys and values.
In this case, `env` is a mapping between strings such as `'AA_PYTHON'` and values, such as `0`.

`var` is a temporary variable used in the [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)

```
((var, os.getenv(var, 0)) for var in vars_of_interest)
```

The `for var in vars_of_interest` in the generator expression tells Python to iterate over the items in the tuple `vars_of_interest`, and assign the values to `var` one-by-one as it iterates through the loop.
The generator expression is an iterator. The iterator yields the values of `(var, os.getenv(var, 0))` for each `var`.

The expression `(var, os.getenv(var, 0))` is a tuple which can be thought of as a key-value pair. `var` is the key, `os.getenv(var, 0)` is the value. [os.getenv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getenv) looks up the environment variable `var` (e.g. `'AA_PYTHON'`) and returns the value of the environment variable if it exists, otherwise, it returns 0.

When `dict` is passed an iterator of key-value pairs, as is being done in the expression

```
dict((var, os.getenv(var, 0)) for var in vars_of_interest)
```

it returns a `dict` which maps the given keys to the given values.

See here for [more information on Python dicts](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 3):

The second example creates a dictionary named `env` using a list comprehension.

What's a dictionary? It's an associative list. One way to think of dictionaries is that they are like arrays, except that instead of being indexed by numbers they are indexed by something else. In this case, they are indexed by a string, the name of an environment variable.

What's a list comprehension? It's a way to create lists. The list that is created by that list comprehension is a list of pairs, environment variable name and the value for that environment variable. The builtin function `dict` creates a dictionary from such a list of pairs.